# opening serial port in java on virtual box returns error

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on virtual box and tried to do serial communication first with javax.comm and rxtx.
In both approaches getPortIdentifiers().toString() just returns "gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator@20d10a" and no actual list of the available ports.

any ideas?

Comment: Is the serial port visible to the virtual box?

Comment: Yes, I already used the serial ports in C programs on the virtual box. worked fine

Comment: It seems that gnu.io.CommPortEnumerator just hasn't got its own implementation for toString(), so it's using the default from java.lang.Object. Did you try calling the hasMoreElements() and nextElement() for it? Peeked from source in here: https://www.knopflerfish.org/svn/knopflerfish.org/trunk/osgi/bundles_opt/serial/rxtxcomm/src/gnu/io/CommPortEnumerator.java

Comment: Did not try that yet but I used CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/sp3virtual"); which through a NoSuchPortException. This is the port I also used to read and write from in C.

Comment: CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();
System.out.println(pid.getName());
this also produces no output.